# how do I check dynamically generated radio input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to generate multiple input fields dynamically for each time user clicks "add" button and I was successfully able to get them. Each contact should have this radio input field in different different name so I've created a name in an array form.

Here's what I have so far and I wonder how I'm supposed to get the radio value for each person:

```
var options = '';
var count = 0;
var maxfields = 4;

$('button#add').click(function() {
  options = '<p>Visit Type:
 <label class="radio-inline">
 <input  type="radio" class="c_visittype' + count +'" name="c_visittype[]" value="Student" required>Student</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" class="c_visittype' + count +'" name="c_visittype[]" value="Visitor" required>Visitor</label> </p>';   


   if(count < maxfields){
        count++;     
    $(options).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('.companion');

    return false;
  }
}); 

 $('.c_visittype' + count).on('click', function(){
    $('input:radio[name="c_visittype"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  });
```

Each person should get a choice of either 'student' or 'visitor' and I have to get this value for multiple persons whenever more person fields created.The reason why I put field's name as an array is to iterate it in the next page by php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="               crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var options = '';
        var count = 0;
        var maxfields = 4;

        $('button#add').click(function() {
            var options = '<p style="display: none">Visit Type:<label class="radio-inline"> <input  type="radio" class="c_visittype' + count +'" name="c_visittype' + count +'[]" value="Student" required>Student</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class="c_visittype' + count +'" name="c_visittype' + count +'[]" value="Visitor" required>Visitor</label> </p>';   

            if(count < maxfields){
                count++;     
                $('.companion').append(options);
                $(".companion p:last").fadeIn();
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>

<button id="add">add</button>
<div class="companion">

</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems working, but would you please elaborate your code? I'm not too familiar with jQuery. My understanding in your solution is to put different names instead of having the same name as an array. I'm surely can get it iterated in php but just like to understand it clearly.

Comment: The unique name is needed for grouping radiobuttons to independent groups. http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm . I append html to the bottom of entire div block - insert it to the DOM. After that I can manipulate it - make it visible in fadeIn.

Comment: trust me, I'd given each radio button a unique id but then it did not break the grouping. As your code works now the cause mighty be linked to the dynamically generating function or how I was calling it. much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=c_visittype[]]:checked').val();
```

That's how you access the value of a checked radio button with jQuery.

Comment: I've already tried all before your suggestion and neither way worked, but thanks for trying.

Comment: Try naming your radio buttons without the '[ ]' and see if that's causing an issue.

Comment: I had tried it too which didn't succeed :(, and i need the name in array for the iteration part in the next page. And that's how I ended up trying varying the class name with counter and it's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputValues = [];
$('.c_visittype:checked').each(function() {
    inputValues.push($(this).val());
});
// Your code using inputValues
```

For update on changes:

```
$(function() {
    $('.c_visittype').click(function(){
        // Insert code here
    }
)});
```

Make sure to move the numbering from the class attribute to the name attribute (like it was, everything was part of the same set of options). Also, put the whole string on 1 line.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't seem to change anything from my original state.

Comment: @lakedejavu What do you mean?

Comment: @lakedejavu Oops, forgot to close all the braces/parens, changed the last line of the  second code block.

Comment: @lakedejavu Also, put make sure to put the whole string on 1 line.